# Filtrar una tabla con el valor de otra tabla

Tags: r

Me gustaría filtrar un tabla acorde con el valor de otra tabla:

En una tabla tengo el valor con el que me gustaría filtrar cada género:

```
    cov.means: 
    genera              mean.coverage
    Nucleorhabdovirus     10.3
    Tritimovirus          2.54
    Potyvirus             5.4
```

Y la tabla en la que me gustaría filtrar acorde con los valores de coverage previamente citados es esta:

```
vir.val.df.uniq:

    sseqid       genera             Lib  mean.coverage 
    NC_000874  Nucleorhabdovirus   PV163   84.14
    NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV002   30.14
    NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV154   44.14
    NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV100   54.14
    NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV098   21.14
    NC_000874  Nucleorhabdovirus   PV163   74.14
    NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV002   06.14
    NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV154   04.14
    NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV100   03.14
    NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV098   01.14
```

Para un valor establecido previamente (10 por ejemplo) se como es la función:

```
vir.val.df.uniq.list <- sort(unique(vir.val.df.uniq$sseqid[vir.val.df.uniq$mean.coverage >= "10"]))
```

Pero no se como relacionar los valores de mean coverage de la primera tabla con la segunda tabla.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si correspondiera trabajar `mean.coverage` como una variable numérica, puedes resolverlo así:

```
vir.val.df.uniq %>% 
  left_join( cov.means,by = c("genera")) %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(mean.coverage.x) > as.numeric(mean.coverage.y)) %>% 
  select(sseqid, genera, Lib, mean.coverage = mean.coverage.x)
```

Comment: ambas opciones funcionan genial, ¡muchas gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que quieres usar los valores de `mean.covered` de la segunda tabla para filtrar los valores mayores o iguales de la primera.

Adapté una solución de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289405/dplyr-left-join-by-less-than-greater-than-condition . Usa `fuzzyjoin::`. Uso `inner_join()` para que solo queden aquellas que tienen match de los lados del join.

```
read_delim("
sseqid       genera             Lib  mean.coverage
NC_000874  Nucleorhabdovirus   PV163   84.14
NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV002   30.14
NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV154   44.14
NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV100   54.14
NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV098   21.14
NC_000874  Nucleorhabdovirus   PV163   74.14
NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV002   06.14
NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV154   04.14
NC_000574  Potyvirus           PV100   03.14
NC_000974  Tritimovirus        PV098   01.14", 
           delim = " ", trim_ws = T) -> foo

read_delim("    genera              mean.coverage
    Nucleorhabdovirus     10.3
    Tritimovirus          2.54
    Potyvirus             5.4", delim = " ", trim_ws = T) -> bar

library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_inner_join(foo, bar,
                 by = c("genera", "mean.coverage"), #El número de columnas de empate debe ser igual al número de funciones de empate 
                 match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`))      # == a genera y >= mean.coverage


   # A tibble: 4 x 4
   sseqid    genera            Lib   mean.coverage
  <chr>     <chr>             <chr> <chr>        
1 NC_000874 Nucleorhabdovirus PV163 84.14        
2 NC_000874 Nucleorhabdovirus PV163 74.14        
3 NC_000574 Potyvirus         PV154 44.14        
4 NC_000574 Potyvirus         PV100 54.14
```

Es muy buena librería `fuzzyjoin`, la había usado para empatar cadenas de caracteres con errores de ortografía, pero para esto también sirve.